# get format on int for awk print

Tags: awk, wc

I want the number of lines of my python files with relative path.

I get that like this::

```
$ find ./ -name "*.py" -exec wc -l {} \;| awk '{print $1, $2}'
29 ./setup.py
28 ./proj_one/setup.py
896 ./proj_one/proj_one/data_ns.py
169 ./proj_one/proj_one/lib.py
310 ./proj_one/proj_one/base.py
0 ./proj_one/proj_one/__init__.py
72 ./proj_one/tests/lib_test.py
```

How could I get (formated ints) like this::

```
 29 ./setup.py
 28 ./proj_one/setup.py
896 ./proj_one/proj_one/data_ns.py
169 ./proj_one/proj_one/lib.py
310 ./proj_one/proj_one/base.py
  0 ./proj_one/proj_one/__init__.py
 72 ./proj_one/tests/lib_test.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [printf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html) with a width [format modifier](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html) to make a formatted column:

```
$ find ./ -name "*.py" -exec wc -l {} \;| awk '{printf "%10s %s\n", $1, $2}'
```

On most platforms, you can print with comma separators as a specifier (if you have BIG files) but the [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Quoting.html#Quoting) can be challenging for command line use:

```
$ echo 10000000 | awk '{printf "%'\''d\n", $1}'
10,000,000
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just pipping the output of find to  `column -t`.

The `column` utility formats its input into multiple columns

`-t` Determine the number of columns the input contains and create a table. Read [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/column)

```
za$ find . -name "*rb" -exec wc -l {} \; | column -t 
20   ./dirIO.rb
314  ./file_info.rb
53   ./file_santizer.rb
154  ./file_writer.rb
58   ./temp/maps.rb
248  ./usefu_ruby.rb
```